# Append New Input to plist in Documents Folder

Tags: ios, objective-c

After much searching of SO I've been able to come up with code to correct previous failures. What I am trying to accomplish is accepting user input from a UITextField and add that input to my TableView, which is populated from a plist. The root value of my plist is dictionary and I would like to keep it as such. My problem is when `writeToFile` is called, I'm completely over writing the existing values instead of inserting, adding or appending to the existing data. It doesn't appear that my attempt to combine the two dictionaries is working, since only the new value is being stored to the plist. Any insight as to where I'm going wrong? The following code is what I have

```
//////////********** Add New Cell When OK is Chosen

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

 UITextField *newDevice = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"newDevice - %@",newDevice.text);

  if (alertView.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 1){

 NSMutableDictionary *input = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[input setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newDevice.text] forKey:@"Room"];


 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.plist"];
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 

 // Combine the two Dictionaries to create one
[dictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:input];

 // Write Combined Dictionary to plist
[dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

 // Add Newly Created text to Table because reload table doesn't do it
[myTableData addObject:newDevice.text];

 // Reload Table Data even though it seems useless 
[myTable reloadData];


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you overwrote the values of the key `Room`.

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

// Get exist input from plist
NSMutableArray *inputFromPlist = dictionary[@"Room"];
// add new object to input
[inputFromPlist addObject:newDevice.text];
// set Room with modified object
[dictionary setObject:inputFromPlist forKey:@"Room"];
// Write Combined Dictionary to plist
[dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
// do something after saving plist ...
```